# Implementar un Snackbar dentro de un Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Tengo un `Asynctask` que basicamente realiza la tarea de **Login** y cuando las credenciales sean correctas y pase la siguiente **Activity** mustre un mensaje de tipo `Snackbar` les comparto el método donde creo que debe ir ...

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        // este método se ejecutará en el subproceso de la interfaz de usuario
        pdLoading.dismiss();

        if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {
            // si sale bien el proceso y se legea correctamente pasa a la activity menuexpositor y finaliza login expositor
            // para que no pueda volver atras. sino que volvera el menu princial
            final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bienvenido/a: "+email,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(formularioExpositor.this,MenuExpositor.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            formularioExpositor.this.finish();

        }else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){

            final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError = new AlertDialog.Builder(formularioExpositor.this);
            alertaDeError.setTitle("Error");
            alertaDeError.setMessage("Credenciales incorrectas.");
            alertaDeError.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            alertaDeError.create();
            alertaDeError.show();

        } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {


            final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(formularioExpositor.this);
            alertaDeError2.setTitle("Error");
            alertaDeError2.setMessage("Ha ocurrido un error inesperado. Intente nuevamente. Verifique su conexión a Internet");
            alertaDeError2.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            alertaDeError2.create();
            alertaDeError2.show();


        }
    }
```

Como ven estoy usando un `Toast` para mostrar el mensaje. Alguna sugerencia ?

Comment: cual es el problema que tienes Felix?

Comment: necesito usar un snackbar en vez de un toast en el caso que las credenciales sean correctas al pasar a la siguiente actividad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero debes crear en tu layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"       
    android:layout_height="match_parent"       
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"       
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"       
    android:id="@+id/snackbarExample">
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

En tu `Activity` crea la siguiente variable

```
View coordinatorLayoutView;
```

En el metodo `onCreate` de tu `Activity` inicializa la variable :

```
coordinatorLayoutView = findViewById(R.id.snackbarExample);
```

Y luego crear en tu metodo `onPost`

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayoutView, "Bienvenido/a: "+email, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.show();
```

Comment: ya había intentado eso y me arroja un error en (getApplicationContext(), "Bienvenido/a: "+email, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG) dice que no puede resolver el metodo ...

Comment: @FelixBeeb actualice mi respuesta, el constructor de SnackBar espera como primer parametro un View.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente !